# Can't read the variable in the loop (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to count the lines which it then converted into list which contains the letter "A" in a specific index but the variable "countword" prints nothing out. How do I get the value from the while loop for "countword"?

```
def test_1():
    with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
        count_lines = 0
        for lines in f:
            count_lines +=1
        count_lines = count_lines - 1 
        line_lists =open("file.txt").readlines()
        i= 0
        while i <= count_lines:
            line_lists[i] = line_lists[i].split(".")
            i +=1
        keyword = "A"
        i=0
        countword = 0
        while i <= count_lines:
            if line_lists[i][4] == keyword:
                countword+=1
                i+=1
        print(countword)
    f.close()
```

Comment: you might be running a infinite loop here as statement `i+=1` is inside if block

Comment: btw there are much simpler ways of looping through the contents of a file.

Comment: You could also just use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) or [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get the count of a keyword in a large string

Comment: As im still a noob here, thanks a lot for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `i+=1` is inside your `if` statement. As long as you encounter a line that does not fulfill the condition, you will be stuck in an infinite loop.